# Not even you vs not even yourself

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to say something like: **You're amazing, don't let anyone tell you differently, not even you/yourself**.

I've found a meme saying: **Trust Nobody, Not Even Yourself** , so I think **yourself** is the correct answer, but I'm not sure if both are correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reflexive pronouns are generally used when the subject and the object are the same person/thing.  In your second example, "trust yourself" is the imperative form of a fairly standard sentence:

> **You** should always trust **yourself**   Trust **yourself**

Your first example is superficially more convoluted, so let me start with a simpler example to establish the pattern:

> You should not let **yourself** smoke so much  Don't let **yourself** smoke so much.

Going back to your first sentence:

> **You** should not let **yourself** tell you differently  Don't let **yourself** tell you differently.

This sentence *sounds* odd to me, but nevertheless I think it's entirely grammatical.  *Yourself* is the object of "let".

However, I also think *you* is fine:

> Don't let anyone -- including **you** -- tell you differently.

Similar sentiment, but here the pronoun is part of the collective "anyone", rather than the object of the verb.  It's an awkward phrasing, though, and might sound wrong to a lot of people.  Personally, I would choose *yourself*.

Comment: Andrew, while I'm with you in terms of the grammar and execution, that final solution just sounds wrong to my American ears.  "...Don't let anyone tell you differently, not even you."?  Technically, I guess it's correct, but it sounds off.  It's not typical.  I think most people would re-word it.

Comment: @user9570789  Agreed.  I added that to the answer.  Although I wouldn't use it, I imagine there are plenty of native speakers who would.